# Import Data to Solr using java

Tags: java, solr

I was trying out to upload data to solr server using java.
Is it possible to do so or to create collection and upload data directly from java, or is there any way to do so.

I found two options using DIH and Tika.

Any advise will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to solrj api: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj. It can be used to upload/search against solr instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Solr in Cloud (ZooKeeper) mode then using solrj you can create collection.
But upload the configuration to be used by SolrCloud before the collection creation command.

If you are using standalone mode then create collection manually.

Sample code to upload Document at solr server using [SOLRJ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj):

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/");
        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();


        doc.addField("id", "1");
        doc.addField("Name", "John");
        doc.addField("RollNo", "101");

        server.add(doc);
        UpdateResponse updateResponse = server.commit();
        System.out.println(updateResponse.getStatus());
```

Make sure you have following entries in **schema.xml** which will be at **conf** folder of **Core**.

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="RollNo" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: But i have text file which has all the data that i want to upload.

Comment: Do you want to upload whole text file or just content of file by extracting from that file.

Comment: I want to upload the content of file by extracting from that.

Comment: Then extract the content and make a document as I have shown in example and upload.

Comment: Its terabyte of data.So impossible to hardcode and upload I guess.

Comment: is it ok, if you upload the whole file?

Comment: Yes,But I nead some to map key pair values.

Comment: then extract that some value and map with and key and for rest of the data import the whole file.

Comment: How to import whole File.

Comment: which type of file you have?

Comment: json and csv both.